# Battery icon (and everything related to battery) missing, upower solutions not working

Tags: gnome, power-management, laptop, battery, acpi

After a recent update (and more probable after trying a few battery Gnome extensions) I lost my battery icon in the tray and found that actually I have nothing related to my battery in settings, tweaks, etc.
So, looks like I have no battery on my laptop although it works enough time unplugged!

I tried reinstalling gnome-power-manager, I tried restarting upower, I even tried fdpowermon, and I tried every kind of solutions offered here (and  everywhere).

So, I use 22.10, Gnome 43.1 on a Dell Inspiron 7348 laptop (with bios updated) and this is what I get:

```
$ acpi
No support for device type: power_supply
```

continue:

```
$ upower -e
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
```

And it doesn't show anything like a `Device: org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0` or `Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`

So:

```
$ upower -d
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Sat 04 Mar 2023 03:13:31 AM +0330 (1491 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          0%
    icon-name:          'battery-missing-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.20
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  no
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

I even installed and tried the other option:

```
$ fdpowermon
No support for device type: power_supply
```

By the way, my battery is working well but I can't see how charged is it, (and anyway I like my battery icon icon up there), So how can I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know when, how , and why there was an "acpi=off" added to my grub :-|
That was it. I just replaced it with "acpi=force" (yes, I insisted to do it), so the lovely battery icon is back up there.

Comment: Hi, I'm a linux newbie and I have the same problem. What exactly do you mean by "added to the grub"? What is the grub and how do I make changes to it?

Answer (score 1):

You might have disabled the **power icon**. It can be enabled using the extension **Just Perfection**. I usually use extension manager to install and manage extensions in my device. Can be installed by;

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

If you're using Extension Manager to handle extensions, Open the software and follow the steps:

1. Under the section installed of Extension Manager. You can search for Just Perfection.
2. If it is not enabled, enable it. Click on the gear icon near the enable button and a popup will open up with the extension settings.
3. Under the icon section enable Power Icon if it is disabled and you should get your power icon back.

- If *Just Perfection* is **not** installed, you can install it from the browse menu and follow the above steps

If that doesn't work try `gnome-shell --replace` in Terminal.

Comment: In the second part of my question, the output of "upower -e" means that the OS doesn't recognize my battery at all. so the problem is not displaying the battery, but recognizing the battery. By the way, I tried "just perfection" after reading your answer and since the OS thinks I have no battery, there wasn't any kind of battery option there to enable or disable.

Comment: Have u tried checking the log?